# NGUI UIInput - Reset value of password field

Tags: unity

How do I reset the value of a NGUI UIInput control that marked `Is Password`. If I set `.text` to "" I still see a bunch of ********** rather than the `.defaultText`.

Basically if the user types the wrong password during login, I want to clear the field and have is display the default text again.

### Update

If I click into the field and back out, the default text shows, but until I do that I get the **********.

Code:

```
// Show the Create dialog
public void ShowCreate() {
    panelWait.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    panelLogin.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    panelCreate.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    username = loginUsername.text;
    createUsername.text = username;
    createPasswordA.text = "";
    createPasswordB.text = "";
}
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: Could you show us your actual code? Because what you describe should just work. Set the `my_uiinput.text = "";` should clear it just fine.

Comment: It might be that the widget doesn't have the focus. Could you try setting `selected` to true and see if that changes anything? i.e. `createPasswordA.selected = true;`

Comment: @Bart - write that as an answer. Had to add all three to make it work right:
    createPasswordB.selected = true;
   createPasswordA.selected = true;
   createUsername.selected = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally setting the `text` member to `""` should clear the `UIInput`. However, for this to take effect, the widget does need to have the focus (`selected` needs to be `true`). If your widget does not immediately clear, you can set its focus manually.

In your case that would be:

```
createPasswordA.selected = true;
createPasswordB.selected = true;
createUsername.selected = true;
```

That should do the trick.